# Porting an existing application to DB2 for I

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

My company is porting our software to a new Database (DB2 for iSeries (7.1)) because of customer wishes. Whe have an automatic upgrading system which drops, alters and creates. The iSeries seems to have a very special way to handle warnings - inquiry messages. As example when i drop our lib via SQL (ADO.NET) the jobs halts and waits for user input.

Is filling SYSRPYL and CALL QSYS2.QCMDEXC('CHGJOB INQMSGRPY(*SYSRPYL)') the only way to get those blocking messages out of the way or is there some global switch so that the iSeries behaves like a normal database? If we need to fill this table is there a way to obtain all relevant messages or do we need to wait to see them happen the first time before we can react?

The other problem seems to be syntax problems - we have our project running on MSSQL, Oracle and DB2 LUW - on iSeries things like using a defined with clause in a join (join something on something.col in (select othercol from W_WithClause)) does not seem to work. Is there a way to make the iSeries to comply to this SQLs or do we need to re-test everything and rewrite our SQLs?

Comment: Any chance you can tell us what messages are being sent? (Especially include message IDs.) Also, is it necessary to drop an entire schema (library) rather than just particular tables, views, etc.?

Comment: "normal database"... Lolz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look at INQMSGRPY(*DFT)...

But you'd have to look at the messages and see if they have a default and what it is.  You can use the Display Message Description (DSPMSGD) command to find the defaults for a message.

For instance, dropping a newly created schema results in at the very least a CPA7025 - Receiver QSQJRN0001 in CWTEST never fully saved. (I C)

The default for that message is I-Ignore.

As far as SQL syntax compatibility, I'm afraid your only choice is to rewrite the statement.  Db2 for i is not Oracle, nor MS SQL Server, nor even DB2 for LUW.  The codebase for DB2 for i is separate from the codebase for DB2 for LUW and DB2 for z/OS for that matter.

If you haven't already found it, the [IBM DB2 for i Porting Information](https://www-356.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/servers/enable/site/db2_porting_i.html) page is a good place to start.

On the plus side, since IBM DB2 for i so closely follows the ANSI/ISO SQL Standards, a statement that works on DB2 for i is likely to work on the others DBs.  It's the non-standard syntax you current have for other DBs that will give you trouble.

On the downside, v7.1 is over 6 years old.  v7.2 was released in 2014 and v7.3 was released this year.  So you're going to be missing out on some newer functionality.  Some enhancements are ported back to earlier releases.
You can take a look at the [DB2 for i - Technology Updates](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/DB2%20for%20i%20-%20Technology%20Updates) page.

Comment: FYI, IBM i 7.3 enhanced `DROP SCHEMA CASCADE` to ignore the CPA7025 (and any journal receiver exit programs).

Answer (score 1):

Best should be to resolve the cause of any message. To address the cause, we need to be sure of what message is being seen. The CPA7025 noted by Charles is most likely, but others are possible depending on the sequence of steps that are involved.

One example of how to resolve the CPA7025 condition might be demonstrated by this SQL statement sequence:

```
CREATE COLLECTION TSTDLTLIB ;

CREATE TABLE TSTDLTLIB.TSTDLT ( K1 ROWID NOT NULL, F1 VARCHAR (20 )
NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT, F2 REAL NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT ) ;

INSERT INTO TSTDLTLIB.TSTDLT VALUES( default, 'Value 1', 999 ) ;

CL: ENDJRNLIB LIB( TSTDLTLIB ) ;
CL: ENDJRNPF FILE( *ALL ) JRN( TSTDLTLIB/QSQJRN ) ;
CL: DLTJRN JRN( TSTDLTLIB/QSQJRN ) ;
CL: DLTJRNRCV JRNRCV( TSTDLTLIB/QSQJRN* ) DLTOPT( *IGNINQMSG ) ;

DROP COLLECTION TSTDLTLIB CASCADE ;
```

The sequence creates a schema with a single simple table, inserts a row into the table, then drops the schema. But before the DROP, a short series of system commands ensures that the default journal that is part of the schema is handled.

A SQL schema will have a journal that is used to maintain commitment control and to assist in recovery. Under IBM i, the journal receivers are required to be properly managed. One expected item is that receivers will be saved before being deleted. Hence, CPA7025, "Receiver &1 in &2 never fully saved."

By ending whatever active journal linkages might exist first, the journal itself may be deleted. Various ENDJRNxxx commands are possible. It might be that only the ENDJRNPF command is needed, but maybe not. After the journal deleted, the associated receivers can be deleted.

The DLTJRNRCV command will delete all receivers generically named QSQJRN* which should fit with a default SQL journal's receivers. And there should be no inquiry messages because the command specifies DLTOPT( *IGNINQMSG ) to "ignore inquiry messages".

Now, how you'd actually implement this will depend on particular details of your process. More can be said if more is known.